# ios gesture recognizer for all types

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I just need to know if there is a way to catch all types of gestures in one instance UIGestureRecognizer.

Example: I have a UIView that I have to detect any type of tap made on it without creating an instance for each type of gesture

is there a way to do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off course it is, handle low level UIView events by yourself ([Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541)):

```
Responding to Touch Events
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
Responding to Motion Events
– motionBegan:withEvent:
– motionEnded:withEvent:
– motionCancelled:withEvent:
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass the `UIGestureRecognizer` class and change its internal state to `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` when touches begin.

Sample code:

```
@interface UITouchGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer

@end
```

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation UITouchGestureRecognizer

- (void) reset
{
    [super reset];
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized;
}

@end
```